# Python tkinter popup not opening prior to subthread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to open a popup that shows a progress bar here, and I'm running into a problem where the popup doesn't open until after the thread completes (the thread starts *after* the popup is called).

Additionally, I *can* get the popup to show before the thread starts by calling `.pack()` on `self.bar` because this errors out as below: (I get the same error if I call `.pack` separate from the `.grid` call)

```
File "\hinter\ui\progress.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.bar.grid(row=2, column=0).pack()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

This is the code where I line everything up:

```
progress_popup = hinter.ui.progress.Progress(0, 'Downloading and processing: Champions') # Should open popup
the_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=self.load_champions,
    args=(refresh,)
)
the_thread.start() # Run the download code in another thread
the_thread.join() # Wait to finish, so downloads can be completed one at a time for now
progress_popup.update(20, 'next') # Update the popup
```

This code is the bulk of `Progress.__init__`, where the popup should open:

```
self.popup = Toplevel()

Label(self.popup, text='Downloading Game data ...').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
self.status_text = Label(self.popup, text=current_status)
self.status_text.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)

self.bar = Progressbar(self.popup, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='determinate')
self.bar['value'] = self.current_percentage
self.bar.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

I am just not understanding why the popup like ... takes so long to open, or something, unless I cause it to error out in which case it opens instantly.

Comment: What do you think should happen when you do `self.bar.grid(row=2, column=0).pack()`? If you call `grid` and then call `pack` (or visa versa) whatever settings were applied first will be thrown away.

Comment: I think to debug the issue we're going to need a [mcve]. That doesn't mean we need your whole program, it just means we need enough to duplicate your results with as few lines as possible.

Comment: @BryanOakley My understanding was that `pack` would draw the dialog, as I assumed the core of the issue was just that it wouldn't draw until something errored with `pack` or the correct drawing method.

Comment: No, `pack` does not draw a dialog. It just lays out the widget in its parent. The dialog appears once `mainloop` has a chance to process the events that tell it to redraw the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Another answer suggested calling `.update()` which did draw everything and resolved my issue. Is that forcing the mainloop to draw my dialog and progress bar, or is it doing something else? I can find little to no documentation on it.

Comment: Yes, `update` forces tkinter to process any pending events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `self.bar.update()` to your `Progress.__init__` method.

`progress_bar.update()` updates the bar with the value set in `progress_bar['value']`, so maybe calling that after setting up the progress bar would make it display?

Like so:

```py
self.popup = Toplevel()

Label(self.popup, text='Downloading Game data ...').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)
self.status_text = Label(self.popup, text=current_status)
self.status_text.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)

self.bar = Progressbar(self.popup, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='determinate')
self.bar['value'] = self.current_percentage
self.bar.grid(row=2, column=0)
self.bar.update()
```

Comment: This solves my problem exactly. `.update()` is all it needed. The only documentation I can find on it though is [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method), and it says to use `.update_idletasks()` when unsure and the idle method doesn't work. Do you have any further documentation on that method?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't... I've looked at my sources and I just realized that the [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvBRhYeO7hc) I saw was the only thing that mentioned it. The other doc I looked in is [Python Docs - TKinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#progressbar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but the explanation for the error is fairly simple: `grid`, `pack`, `place` always return `None`, so something like this:

```
self.bar.grid(row=2, column=0).pack()
```

... will be the same as `None.pack()`, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Trying to use both `grid` and `pack` on a widget is pointless. Only one geometry manager will control a widget, so calling `self.bar.grid()` followed by `self.bar.pack()` will throw away any work done by `self.bar.grid()`.

Comment: This explains the error I was getting, but doesn't explain why the progress bar and popup dialog do not draw prior to the subthread completing, which is the core of the question. Is `.grid()` supposed to do that, or am I missing a call that is similar to `.pack()`?

Comment: @zbee: no, neither `grid` nor `pack` have anything to do with threads or displaying popups.